# Problems download file (apk) using jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I'm having problems when making a download apk from page in html, this happens with Andorid devices that use browser "Chrome".

The problem is, when you click on the download link from browser chrome begins to cycle the page "n" number of times without finish downloading the file, I been attempted solved with HTML5 with sentences of download href "" download. Tests with jquery and a script that invokes the download was tested and finally make different statements within the simple HTML were also made.

NOTE: THIS ONLY HAPPENS IN CHROME BROWSER IN OTHER BROWSERS LOW FILE NO PROBLEM.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Prueba HTML5 SDK</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function(evento) {
            alert("Deseas descargar version de Android");

            < ul >

            < a href = "https://www.bancomermovil.net:11443/mbank/mbank/Descargas/BPromo/android/V62/SuiteBancomerBBVANow.apk" > Descargar! < /a>
         </ul >
```

Comment: You didn't close the script tag, you didn't close the `head` and you didn't open and close your body tag. I suppose you *did* do that in your actual file, but for completeness' sake, you might want to post the **exact** code you used.

Comment: do you enable popup ??

Comment: Yes i close the script tag but i dindt put  here, the real code:
 <meta charset="utf-8" /><title>Prueba HTML5 SDK</title>
 <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
 <script> $("a").click(function(evento) 
          {
              evento.preventDefault();
              var href = $(this).attr('href') + '?' + Math.random();
              window.location.href = href;
          });</script> </head> <body>
<ul><a href="https://www.bancomermovil.net:11443/mbank/mbank/Descargas/BPromo/android/V62/SuiteBancomerBBVANow.apk">Descargar!</a>
         </ul></body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to generate a unique href for every click on the link element:

```
$("a").click(function(evento) 
{
        evento.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href') + '?' + Math.random();
        window.location.href = href;
});
```

this way chrom will not cache your request and treat every download like its the first

Comment: Continue the page with de problem 

 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Prueba HTML5 SDK</title>
         <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>
 $("a").click(function(evento) 
          {
              evento.preventDefault();
              var href = $(this).attr('href') + '?' + Math.random();
              window.location.href = href;
          });
 </script>
 <ul>
           
            <a href="https://www.bancomermovil.net:11443/mbank/mbank/Descargas/BPromo/android/V62/SuiteBancomerBBVANow.apk">Descargar!</a>
    </ul>